# Find relative position of a keyword in a column with text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, formula

Goal: Get the content of a cell in sheet 2 (column E) by searching for a keyword from sheet 1 in sheet 2.

To get the content I just need the relative position (row number) of the right cell in sheet 2 by looking for the unique keyword (sheet 1 column A) in sheet 2 column B.

**sheet 1 column A (keywords):**

```
1234567
7453773
9876543
```

Challenge: the cells in column B in sheet 2 includes not just one keyword (id) but several.

**sheet 2 column B:**

```
1234567 7453773 9876543
```

If there is just one keyword per cell the following formula works fine:

```
=index('sheet 2'!$E$2:$E,match(a2,'sheet 2'!$B$2:$B,0),1)
```

How can I find the relative row number if the cells include more keywords, separated by spaces?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QspuFjYcbw9Ff6B0TfegJGHrBu2dSEE1MRwY7jVqbrw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(A4:A7, Source!A2:B5, 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP("*"&A4:A7&"*", Source!A2:B5, 2, 0))))
```

[image]